# MySQL Query using joins and multiple AND's not quite working

Tags: mysql

This is my query:

```
SELECT dt1.*, document.* 
FROM documenttags dt1 
LEFT JOIN document ON dt1.id = document.id 
WHERE 
  (dt1.tag = 'agent' AND dt1.value = 'excel' ) 
AND 
  (dt1.tag = 'extension' AND dt1.value = 'xls' )
```

The query will work fine up until the `AND` after the first `tag` and `value` pair:

```
SELECT dt1.*, document.* 
FROM documenttags dt1 
LEFT JOIN document ON dt1.id = document.id 
WHERE (dt1.tag = 'agent' AND dt1.value = 'excel' )
```

A typical result of the second query is :

`id   | tag  | value | ...rest of columns'

'11 | agent | excel | ... rest of columns`

And finally, a search for `id=11` yields:

`id   | tag  | value |`
`11   | agent | excel |`
`11   | extension| xls|`

So I'm really puzzled why my original query doesn't work?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not quite working"? What does it do as compared to what you want it to do?

Comment: by not quite working I mean it returns zero results. I would like it to find all the documents in the table that have the `tag` `agent` where the `value` is `excel` and the `tag` `extension` where the `value` is `xls`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably meant this from the beginning but I didn't get it.

What you want (as I think now), is to correlate a (row from table) `document` to **2 or more** (rows from) `documenttags`. This can be achieved with 2 or more `JOIN`s from table documents to documenttags, as below.

If you have 3 criteria, you'll need 3 `JOIN`s, etc.

The following query will give you all documents that have both `excel` tagged as `agent`, **and** `xls` tagged as `extension`:

(Sidenote: yes, you were right, "AND" is the correct term to use here!)

```
SELECT dt1.*
     , dt2.*
     , document.*  
FROM document 
  JOIN documenttags dt1 
    ON dt1.id = document.id
  JOIN documenttags dt2
    ON dt2.id = document.id
WHERE 
  (dt1.tag = 'agent' AND dt1.value = 'excel' ) 
  AND
  (dt2.tag = 'extension' AND dt2.value = 'xls' )
```

This would work too. With one JOIN and a grouping:

```
SELECT document.*
     , COUNT(document.id) AS filtersPassed  
FROM document 
  JOIN documenttags dt
    ON dt.id = document.id
      --filters (conditions) go here:
WHERE (dt.tag = 'agent' AND dt.value = 'excel')
   OR (dt.tag = 'extension' AND dt.value = 'xls')
GROUP BY document.id
HAVING filtersPassed = 2             --number of filters
```

Using `OR` here because the query works like this:

For every document, it checks all related rows and keeps those according to your conditions. We can't use `AND` here as every row is checked one by one and of course a row cannot have two tags, just one. So, we keep all good tags and then we group them together and count how many there are for every document  (grouping is the usual way to count rows in SQL.) Then we just have to keep documents that passed both filters (`= 2`).

Second query has the advantage that can be used for a more complex query, if for example you have 4 filters and you want to find documents that pass 3 or 4 of those filters. Just put the 4 conditions (with `OR`s) and `filtersPassed >= 3`.

Comment: +1, nice solution, unfortunately for OP it seems like the table design is really flawed and sooner or later will face bigger problems.. :-/

Comment: hi, regarding the second query using one JOIN and a grouping - why is it you are using OR for this instead of AND?

Comment: hi andre, the table structure is not of my own design and to change it would be very painful, there are literally millions of documents involved. the structure does what it needs to so I need to just do my best to work around it I'm afraid :/

Comment: Hi ypercube, just tested your second query - it seems to return lots of irrelevant search results? Not sure why that is though....

Comment: @andre: for the record I don't see any fatal flaws in the db design. If the total number of tags used for the documents is small, they could have been put as fields in table `document`. If the number is big that would not be possible. Plus, as it is, any number of tags can be added without changing the table's structure. It's designer's choice really and I probably would have done the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell,
- `dt1.tag` can't be both `agent` and `extension` 
just like
- `dt1.value` can't be both `excel` and `xls`.

Consider changing your `AND` to an `OR`.

```
SELECT dt1.*, document.* 
FROM documenttags dt1 
LEFT JOIN document ON dt1.id = document.id 
WHERE 
  (dt1.tag = 'agent' AND dt1.value = 'excel' ) 
OR  -- it was an AND previously
  (dt1.tag = 'extension' AND dt1.value = 'xls' )
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I need it to work with an AND aswel as an OR. It is a query based from an advanced search form and the AND and the OR are constructed in the query based on if the user wants a complete match or something that fits any of the criteria.

Comment: Well, in that case: the original query will work. But will never return any values because the first expression `(dt1.tag = 'agent' AND dt1.value = 'excel' )` and the second `(dt1.tag = 'extension' AND dt1.value = 'xls' )` can never be true at the same time...

Comment: I don't understand thought why it doesn't work, from what I can see it should find the rows in the table with the same id number that have `agent` in the `tag` column and `excel` in the `value` column and also `extension` in the `tag` column and `xls` in the `value` `column`?

Comment: I'm sorry but what you see is wrong. What the original query states is something like this `SELECT everything FROM documenttags and LEFT JOIN document. Filter results by the following criteria: (dt1.tag = 'agent' and dt1.value = 'excel') and at the same time (dt1.tag = 'extension' and dt1.value = 'xls')`. For each result row `dt1.tag` for instance, can only have 1 value, never both. Try the query I've posted and tell me if that's not the result you expect?

Comment: @martin: Use `OR`. Use `OR` there. You want the data that have that attribute **AND ALSO** data that have that other attribute. SQL wants you to say "I want all data that have either that **OR** that other attribute". It's the same thing, different syntax.

Comment: @ypercube: hm? I'm sorry, I didn't get it. Did I explain it wrong somewhere? Anyway, what you said is right and probably easier to understand than any other thing I said: @martincarlin87 `want all data that have either that OR that other attribute`.

Comment: I'm still confused :S

I ran the query andrew matos posted and from what I can see it returns all the documents that are `excel` `OR` have `xls` as a function, but suppose it was possible for a document to have `excel` as an `agent` and an `extension` such as `xlsx` and I only wanted files that exactly matched that criteria, then surely I would get `xls` files returned in the results?

Comment: @andre: Sorry, i put wrong @recipinient (you, instead of OP) when i posted comment. Edited now.

Comment: @martin: For your last comment problem, I think you need a second join. See my answer.

Comment: @martincarlin87: Well, for that you need a different WHERE condition. Something like `WHERE (dt1.tag = 'agent' AND dt1.value = 'excel') AND (dt1.tag = 'extension' AND dt1.value = 'xlsx')`. Somewhere in the process you'll have to find out if your second condition will filter (AND) the first a little further or if the second condition is independent (OR) from the first.

Answer (score 1):

I think, if possible, that you should consider changing your schema.

Why not adding **agent** and **extension** fields directly to your **document table** (or related specific tables, such as for example `document_agent` and `document_extension` if a document can have several agents and extensions) ?

Comment: a doucment can only have one agent and extension, it's just that the criteria for each document is stored in one massive table.

Comment: I fear, then, that a schema change as the one I suggested (add **agent** and **extension** fields to your **document** table) is mandatory.

Comment: The change you suggest might be good. But it's only possible if there are only these 2 tags (agent and extension) or just a few tags. If the number of tags used totally is big, then this approach is far better.